# Push duplicate values to another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array, which contains duplicate values. How can I push duplicates in to another array?

`let arr1 = [1, 5, 3, 6, 9, 5, 1, 4, 2, 7, 9]`, and duplicates array should be `dupArr = [1, 5, 9]`

Comment: This is fairly simple and can be done in various ways, what have you tried?

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132232/how-to-keep-duplicates-of-an-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep Duplicates of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132232/how-to-keep-duplicates-of-an-array)

Comment: I have two arrays, which I get from my reducer (one of them contains second array's some datas), and I want to mark with colored star those items, which I have in both arrays, and mark others with white star.

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks a lot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter the array by storing the previous checked values in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which is here a closure.

```js
var array = [1, 5, 3, 6, 9, 5, 1, 4, 2, 7, 9],
    duplicates = array.filter((s => v => s.has(v) || !s.add(v))(new Set));
    
console.log(duplicates);
```