# Complex selection and table

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array named `listSelected` which feeds after each selection in another grid.

```
const listSelected =    
 [{    
    "_id": "10",    
    "age": 35,    
    "name": "Paige Zamora",    
    "gender": "female",    
    "company": "AUTOMON",    
    "**reference_id": "12**"    
  },    
  {    
    "_id": "11",    
    "age": 40,    
    "name": "Jennifer Carr",    
    "gender": "female",    
    "company": "SYNKGEN",    
    "**reference_id": "11**"    
  }];
```

I would like to check that for each value `reference_id` one checks in another table named `data` if this value exists, we get the value `id` in a new array, even if the value `reference_id` is present several times.

```
const data = [{    
    "_id": "**10**",    
    "age": 35,    
    "name": "Paige Zamora",    
    "gender": "female",    
    "company": "AUTOMON",    
    "**reference_id": "12**"    
  },    
  {    
    "_id": "**11**",    
    "age": 40,    
    "name": "Jennifer Carr",    
    "gender": "female",    
    "company": "SYNKGEN",    
    "**reference_id": "11**"    
  },    
  {    
    "_id": "**12**",    
    "age": 38,    
    "name": "Weaver Rosales",    
    "gender": "male",    
    "company": "ETERNIS",    
    "**reference_id": "12**"    
  },    
  {
    "_id": "13",    
    "age": 31,    
    "name": "Myers Pickett",    
    "gender": "male",    
    "company": "ETERNIS",    
    "reference_id": "13"    
  },    
  {    
    "_id": "14",    
    "age": 36,    
    "name": "Dona Nicholson",    
    "gender": "female",    
    "company": "ETERNIS",    
    "reference_id": "14"    
  },    
  {
    "_id": "15",    
    "age": 21,    
    "name": "Niki Blur",    
    "gender": "female",    
    "company": "AUTOMON",    
    "reference_id": "15"    
  },    
  {    
    "_id": "16",    
    "age": 37,    
    "name": "Bod Dennart",    
    "gender": "male",    
    "company": "SYNKGEN",    
    "reference_id": "16"    
  },    
  {    
    "_id": "17",    
    "age": 26,    
    "name": "Richard Nelson",    
    "gender": "male",    
    "company": "ETERNIS",    
    "reference_id": "17"    
  },    
  {    
    "_id": "**12**",    
    "age": 45,    
    "name": "Pedro Kluivert",    
    "gender": "female",    
    "company": "SYNKGEN",    
    "**reference_id": "18**"    
  }    
];
```

In the end the new grid will give the following data:

```
const newGrid = [11,12]
```

I was thinking of using two nested `forEach` functions, like these :

```
const newGrid = [];

listSelected.forEach((elt) => {
  data.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.reference_id === elt.reference_id) {
       newGrid.push(item.id);
       newGrid = Array.from(new Set(newGrid));
     }
   });
});
```

Is there not a simpler way to simplify this function to avoid using nested `forEach` ?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Please at least provide the end result, so that we know what to aim for.

Comment: The final result is indicated in the post.  **newGrid = [11,12]**

Comment: It is the data array ? Because in your nested loops, you seem to use it ...

Comment: Oh so just a count ?

Comment: Must we absolutely use two forEach ?

Comment: No, as stated in several answers, you can use other operators on your arrays. I also have posted a solution implying a single loop in the code, to avoid nested loops (be warned that `indexOf` still makes two loops, it's just your code that looks "cleaner")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a "reverse-unique" array :

```js
const listSelected = [
  { "_id": "10", "age": 35, "name": "Paige Zamora", "gender": "female", "company": "AUTOMON", "reference_id": "12" }, 
  { "_id": "11", "age": 40, "name": "Jennifer Carr", "gender": "female", "company": "SYNKGEN", "reference_id": "11" }
];

const data = [
  { "_id": "10", "age": 35, "name": "Paige Zamora", "gender": "female", "company": "AUTOMON", "reference_id": "12" }, 
  { "_id": "11", "age": 40, "name": "Jennifer Carr", "gender": "female", "company": "SYNKGEN", "reference_id": "11" }, 
  { "_id": "12", "age": 38, "name": "Weaver Rosales", "gender": "male", "company": "ETERNIS", "reference_id": "12" }, 
  { "_id": "13", "age": 31, "name": "Myers Pickett", "gender": "male", "company": "ETERNIS", "reference_id": "13" }, 
  { "_id": "14", "age": 36, "name": "Dona Nicholson", "gender": "female", "company": "ETERNIS", "reference_id": "14" }, 
  { "_id": "15", "age": 21, "name": "Niki Blur", "gender": "female", "company": "AUTOMON", "reference_id": "15" }, 
  { "_id": "16", "age": 37, "name": "Bod Dennart", "gender": "male", "company": "SYNKGEN", "reference_id": "16" }, 
  { "_id": "17", "age": 26, "name": "Richard Nelson", "gender": "male", "company": "ETERNIS", "reference_id": "17" }, 
  { "_id": "12", "age": 45, "name": "Pedro Kluivert", "gender": "female", "company": "SYNKGEN", "reference_id": "18" }
];

const merged = [
  ...listSelected.map(item => item.reference_id),
  ...data.map(item => item.reference_id)
];

const reverseUnique = merged.filter((item, index, array) => array.indexOf(item) === index && array.lastIndexOf(item) !== index);

console.log(reverseUnique);
```

This only makes one loop, instead of every other method doing two nested (because yes, `filter/find/some` do a loop over the array)

You start by concatenating the two arrays in a single one, and using only the reference ID.

Then, you use [the opposite of a unique filtering function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132232/how-to-keep-duplicates-of-an-array).

Comment: so you are saying others are using two nested loops! what do you think the runtime of array.indexof() method?

Comment: @GolamRahmanTushar maybe you should check the comments on the question.

Comment: so you think, instead of using find method inside forEach, first merging the arrays and then writing a single for loop with two nested forloops inside it, is much more clean?

Comment: Where did I say that ? I provided a solution implying a single loop (understand, "not nested functions") instead of two nested functions. But if you ask me what is the cleanest, then `reduce` would be. Maybe you should stop talking to me, you seem to have an issue with my self and you don't actually criticize the answer, but rather my personal opinions.

Comment: I think you criticized other's answer and devoted them saying your answer is better without stating any valid reasoning. stop doing this. and this is my last comment.

Comment: @GolamRahmanTushar never said my answer was better. You did about yours though. Sure, bye.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the find method of array like following:

```
newGrid = [];

listSelected.forEach((elt) => {

    newGrid.push(data.find(function check(item) {

        return item.reference_id === elt.reference_id;

    }).reference_id);
});
```

Comment: `find` still does a loop over the array.

Comment: yes, I know. but he/she asked for a way to avoid using nested ForEach.

Comment: true that, but I hardly believe he just wants to just replace the operator.

Comment: what you believe doesn't matter here. clearly he is searching for cleaner code not thinking about the runtime.

Comment: "Clean code" is a matter of beliefs too ... Why do you think nested `forEach` are worse than `forEach/find` ? That's totally biased of you.

Comment: because it looks better. if not why do you think they provide these utility methods?

Comment: No it doesn't. it looks the same. Two function nested into one another. And they provide those operators to do different things. If you think `find` and `forEach` do the same, then learn about them !

Answer (score -1):

```
const newGrig = listSeleced.map(listItem => {
    if (data.some(dataItem => dataItem.item.reference_id === listItem.item.reference_id) {
        return listItem.reference_id;
    }
    return;
});
```

Have not tested this, but it should work. You could also do something similar with reduce.