# Remove non duplicate objects from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a very simple array:

```
var arr = [{id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 3, score: 20}, {id: 4, score: 5}];
```

I want to remove those object which has only single occurrence e.g:

```
{id: 3, score: 20}
{id: 4, score: 5}
```

So the final output should be:

```
[{id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 1, score: 10}]
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i].id === arr[j].id && arr[i].score === arr[j].score) {
            result.push({ id: arr[i].id, score: arr[i].score })             
        }
    }
}
```

But this is removing my duplicates as well, e,g it gives me this result:

```
[{id: 1, score: 10}]
```

But i need this result:

```
[{id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 1, score: 10}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep Duplicates of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132232/how-to-keep-duplicates-of-an-array)

Comment: is the array sorted by `id` and `score`?

Comment: I'm fascinated by the potential use-case you have for this.

Comment: You're starting your inner loop from `i + 1` - if you'd started it from 0 again, you'd get what you need.

Comment: @NinaScholz its not sorted in any way yet. I have bigger array in original, this is just a use case

Comment: If it's not sorted, then if you have duplicates that are not next to each other, they will not be kept.

Answer (score 7):

`Array.filter` will help

Filter the array with combination of `id` and `score`, check if the length of this comination is greater than 1, which means there are more than one occurance of this combination.

```js
const arr = [{ id: 1, score: 10 }, { id: 1, score: 10 }, { id: 3, score: 20 }, { id: 4, score: 5 }, { id: 77, score: 25, type: 'notthisone' }];
const newArr = arr.filter(item => arr.filter(x => x.id === item.id && x.score === item.score).length > 1 || item.type === 'notthisone');
console.log(newArr);
```

**Your fixed solution.**

You have to push the value from `arr` for both index `i` and `j`. But the index node for `i` must be pushed only once.

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 3, score: 20}, {id: 4, score: 5}, {id: 77, score: 25, type: 'notthisone'}];
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let isFound = false;
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[i].id === arr[j].id && arr[i].score === arr[j].score) {
      isFound = true;
      result.push(arr[j]);
    }
  }
  if(isFound ||  arr[i].type === 'notthisone') {
      result.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

**Edit:** If you want to have one specific object having particular value for key `type`, then you can include that in the condition. I have updated the answer with that.

Comment: This works fine. what if I am willing to remove specific non duplicate records? E,g those unique records whose type == 'notthisone'

Comment: considering following array: const arr = [{id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 3, score: 20}, {id: 4, score: 5}, {id: 77, score: 25, type: 'notthisone'}]; Now here I am expecting following response: [{id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 77, score: 25, type: 'notthisone'}]

Comment: @StormTrooper If you want to have one specific object having particular value for key `type`, then you can include that in the condition. I have updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop and an object for keeping track of the first of reference for the same item.

```js
const
    array =  [{ id: 1, score: 10, x: 1 }, { id: 1, score: 10, x: 2, }, { id: 3, score: 20 }, { id: 4, score: 5 }, { id: 77, score: 25, type: 'notthisone' }],
    getKey = ({ id, score }) => JSON.stringify({ id, score }),
    result = array
        .map((q => o => {
            if (o.type === 'notthisone') return o;

            const
                key = getKey(o), 
                target = [];
            q[key] ??= { value: undefined, target };
            if (q[key].value) {
                q[key].target[0] ??= q[key].value;
                return o;
            }
            q[key].value = o;
            return target;
        })({}))
        .flat();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works fine. what if I am willing to remove specific non duplicate records? E,g those unique records whose type == 'notthisone'. considering following array: const arr = [{id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 3, score: 20}, {id: 4, score: 5}, {id: 77, score: 25, type: 'notthisone'}]; Now here I am expecting following response: [{id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 1, score: 10}, {id: 77, score: 25, type: 'notthisone'}]

Comment: you could add a check for special objects in advance. please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) combined with [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (`Array.find` is less 'expensive' than `Array.filter`). Something like (also took your question on @Nitheesh' answer into account):

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 1, score: 10}, 
  {id: 1, score: 10}, 
  {id: 3, score: 20}, 
  {id: 4, score: 5}, 
  {id: 77, score: 25, include: true} ];

const log =  document.querySelector(`pre`);
log.textContent = `**Reduced\n${
  JSON.stringify(retrieveDuplicates(arr), null, 2)}`;
log.textContent += `\n\n**Looped\n${
  JSON.stringify(retrieveDuplicatesLoop(arr), null, 2)}`;

// reducer
function retrieveDuplicates(arr) {
  return arr.reduce( ( acc, v, i ) => {
    const exists = v.include ? v :
      arr.slice(i+1).find( vv => v.id === vv.id && v.score === vv.score );
    acc = !acc.length && exists ? acc.concat({...v}) : acc;
    return exists ? [...acc, {...exists}] : acc; 
  }, [] );
}

// Or in a classic loop
function retrieveDuplicatesLoop(arr) {
  let result = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    const exist = arr[i].include ? arr[i] : 
      arr.slice(i+1).find(v => arr[i].id === v.id && arr[i].score === v.score);
    if (!result.length && exist) { result.push(arr[i]); }
    result = exist && result.concat(arr[i]) || result;
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```